# Automatic run testcases using protractor, selenium server with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am able to write testcases using protractor, selenium server with angularjs,

Is it possible to automatic run testcase at some interval of time and store their result somewhere(i.e failed or success etc.)?

Comment: try junkins or hudson tools.

Comment: Right, Jenkins is the right tool though it needs some setup. There is nothing ready to plug-in / out of the works that would just work without getting hands dirty on our side. Another option would be some grunt task that watches for file changes and run protractor if any, also you need to set it up yourself.

Comment: @LeoGallucci this is actually an answer, please post :)

Comment: I'm lazy to provide the grunt watch or google to see if it's already there that's way is just a comment :D

Comment: can someone provide me the link for step by step working to achieve automatic testing of protractor E2E test cases, I have already written test cases using protractor, selenium and angularjs, but i have required to run this automatic and if possible without open any browser, I have search for junkins, but till now not got the perfect link to achieve my requirements.

Comment: I have seen jasmine and grunt, but I think they will work if found any change in file, but I have required to run all testcases after some interval(still if there is no change in file)

Comment: thanks to all of you, I have acheive my requirement using jenkins, i have follows this link  

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-continuous-integration-continuous-deployment-with-jenkins--cms-21511

Comment: Now is it possible that i can get result of testcases after their execution(in any form either this save somewhere or mail to me)